# How to run Docker image and configure it with nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, devops

I have made a Docker image for a nodeJS and it is running in Local perfectly but in Production, I have to configure it with Nginx(Which I installed in the host machine). We normally did like

```
location /location_of_app_folder {
    proxy_pass http://api.prv:51967/info;
}
```

How will I configure this in nginx for docker image and how to run docker image. We used pm2 in nodeJS wch I added in Docker file But it is running till I press **ctrl+C**.

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN npm config set registry http://private.repo/:_authToken=authtoken.
RUN npm install utilities@0.1.9
RUN apk update && apk add yarn python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN set NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN ls -al -R
EXPOSE 51967
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json" ]
```

I am running the container with the command:

```
sudo docker run -it --network=host docker_repo_name
```

Comment: I'm confused, is nginx also running in a container or is it on the host machine?

Comment: @zero298 it is running in host machine

Comment: What command are you using to actually run this image?

Comment: In local Im just using "sudo docker run -it --network=host docker_repo_name"

Comment: `-it` means the container will run in the forground.  You should run it detatched using `-d` without the `-it`.  Please read over the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d).

Comment: okay then how will configure it with nginx @zero298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expose the docker image port and use the same nginx configuration, ex:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 51967:51967 docker_repo_name
```